# Please identify this SOT363 SMD marked mAHG

Tags: amplifier, integrated-circuit, identification, components

Please help me identify this 6-pin SMD marked mAHG (mAGS):

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

SIP-Phone Yealink SIP-T19

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can be [RT9011](https://www.richtek.com/assets/product_file/RT9011/DS9011-09.pdf) (dual channel LDO), judging from the presence of ceramic caps (possibly for decoupling) at pin5 (VIN).

Answer (score 0):

Installed a jumper pin 1 - pin 4.  Its work!
I will order analog switch.

Comment: You edited the answer in your question and posted a comment as answer.